# Nokogiri gem not working

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am using Rvm and ruby 2.1.5p273.

Installed nokogiri by: 
            `gem install nokogiri`

It installs perfectly:

```
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.5
Parsing documentation for nokogiri-1.6.5
Done installing documentation for nokogiri after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

After typing:

```
gem list | grep nokogiri
```

I get: 
    `nokogiri (1.6.5)`

This is all on Mac Yosemite.

```
require 'nokogiri'
```

shows: `LoadError: cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri`

I searched all over SO and other forums, for hours no solution is working.

```
gem env
```

gives:

```
RubyGems Environment:
```

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/mac/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
     - /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin
     - /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin
     - /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin
     - /usr/local/heroku/bin
     - /Users/mac/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/mac/.rbenv/bin
     - /Users/mac/.pyenv/bin
     - ./node_modules/.bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/git/bin
     - /Users/mac/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
     - /opt/nginx/sbin
     - /Users/mac/.bash_it/plugins/available/todo
     - /Users/mac/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/mac/android-sdks/platform-tools/

```
rvm info
```

gives

```
ruby-2.1.5:
```

system:
    uname:       "Darwin macs-MacBook-Pro.local 14.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    system:      "osx/10.10/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.53(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)"
    zsh:         "/usr/local/bin/zsh => zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0)"

rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.26.4 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin , Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "1 month 25 days 17 hours 46 minutes 45 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/mac/.rvm"

ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.1.5p273"
    date:         "2014-11-13"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin14.0"
    patchlevel:   "2014-11-13 revision 48405"
    full_version: "ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]"

homes:
    gem:          "/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5"
    ruby:         "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5"

binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin/rake"

environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/mac/.rbenv/shims:/Users/mac/.rbenv/bin:/Users/mac/.pyenv/bin:./node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/mac/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/opt/nginx/sbin:/Users/mac/.bash_it/plugins/available/todo:/Users/mac/.rvm/bin:/Users/mac/android-sdks/platform-tools/"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5:/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""

Comment: how are you running the code?

Comment: @UriAgassi : Running it in irb

Comment: try running `bundle exec irb`

Comment: But I am not running this inside any project.. so this just shows:
`Could not locate Gemfile` . As expected, if I am not wrong.

Comment: Append the output of `gem env` and `rvm info` to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following stuffs:

```
brew update
xcode-select --install
brew install libiconv
brew link libiconv
```

Then try these:

```
 gem pristine nokogiri
 gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14
 or
 bundle install
```

Also please check if you are properly loaded your right gemset/ruby version.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work though.
What do you mean by properly loaded your right gemset/ruby version ?

Answer (score -2):

I also had the same problem and just adding `sudo` worked perfectly fine with me

i.e Your command to install nokogiri is : `gem install nokogiri` now try adding sudo that will be like the following

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: Do *NOT* use `sudo` to install gems on a Mac OS system unless you understand how it affects Apple's installed Ruby. Also, `sudo` with RVM/rbenv managed gems will not help, and can actually cause more problems. Specifically, the RVM authors say to NOT use `sudo` at all.